# Definir variable en función formato lista por comprensión

Tags: lista, haskell

Tengo este pseudocódigo en PSeInt que calcula el factorial de un número dado por el usuario.

```
Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir i, tmp, x Como Enteros;
    tmp<-1;
    Escribir "Ingrse un número para calcular su factorial";
    Leer x;
    Para i <- 1 Hasta x Hacer
        tmp<-tmp * i;
    FinPara
    Escribir tmp;
FinProceso
```

Ahora quisiera implementar el mismo código en Haskell usando listas por comprensión

```
import Data.IORef

factorial::Int -> Int
factorial x = [tmp|i<-[1..x], modifyIORef tmp (*i)]
```

Tira error diciendo variable `tmp` no definida

¿Como hago para definir la variable `tmp`, a los efectos de poder usarla?